# listen to tcp events in win CE

Tags: tcp, compact-framework, listener, windows-ce

A device is sending events every second, from 192.168.101.4 to 192.168.101.2:4002.
I need to listen and parse these events, but i fail already with the listening part.

Could someone please explain, how to do this with limited options of compact framework?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: i had success with a connected socket and the function "socket.receive()" but only directly after sending a package.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of the code you're using and point to where it's failing and what error you're getting? Without knowing your specific issue all I can do is point you to a general socket tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it on my own, but thanks PaulH for the helpful tutorial.

For programmers with the same problem:

```
    /// <param name="port">Port to use</param>
    /// <param name="size">count of bytes to return</param>
    /// <returns>a byteArray with received data</returns>
    public static byte[] readEvent(int port, int size)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
        TcpListener listener;
        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
            listener.Start();
            TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            listener.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```